# 18.04 KDE screenlocker showing full username for Local Users, but not for remote (LDAP authenticated) users

Tags: kde, lock-screen, pam, ldap

I've got an issue where my KDE screenlocker will not show the full username for the logged in user (for this session) if that user is LDAP authenticated.
This means that when the screen is locked, you can't see who locked it.

It displays the full username for a locally created/authenticated user so the theme is at least functional for a single user.

[edit] I've confirmed the file:

`/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/lockscreen/LockScreenUi.qml`

is the one being referenced by my theme

`getent` returns remote users and groups as expected, with full username fields in exactly the same format as `getent` for the local user, so it's not an issue with LDAP access/results.

I've built a kde app using [this tutorial](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/First_program), and can verify that the following code snippet (from kscreenlocker-5.12.8, `greeter/greeterapp.cpp:300`) does return the correct fullName for an LDAP authenticated user:

```
        const KUser user;
        const QString fullName = user.property(KUser::FullName).toString();
```

[edit2] - thanks to @WinEunuuchs2Unix I am slightly closer:

The logout screen has functioning fullUsername code. This can be found in:

```
/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/logout/Logout.qml
```

I've [patched the `LockScreenUi.qml` file](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mfvvh8734g/), and verified it's functional by the commented `name: "foobar"` line, but for some reason `kuser.fullname` is still returning nothing.

[end edit]

How do I get the LDAP full username to display correctly on the lockscreen?

Thanks for any assistance -

Screenshots -

[image: Local User (full username displayed)]

[image: LDAP User (no username displayed)]

Answer (score 1):

I've found a similar post with additional details that may benefit you:

- [KDE Plasma lock screen not showing user](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/532210-KDE-Plasma-lock-screen-not-showing-user)

An interesting point is during "Log out" the LDAP the user name does show up even though it doesn't on lock screen. You might want to look there for your source code changes.

Another approach would be to find everywhere in Ubuntu the user name appears and stuff that field with the LDAP user name.

Sorry but this is all I could come up with...

Comment: Hey thanks for the link - I had run across it. The specifics of how sssd works differently to my setup (which is basic pam ldap modules) was something I wasn't ready to dig into, but I missed the bit about the logout link. I will dig some more this week - thanks again, appreciate your time

Comment: TIL the bounty goes *POOF* if you don't award it... sorry, I would've just given it to you if I'd known :( https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3137/what-happens-to-bounty-points-that-are-not-awarded/3144

Comment: @cleary That's perfectly all right. I've earned my fair share of bounties and have been jokingly referred to as a bounty hunter so loosing some every now and then is good for non-point reputation. The important thing to me is you eventually figure out the problem....